# CocoaPods how to install one new library without update other

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I think a question need not be described. Usually when I do `pod install` it updates for me all my libraries. How can I add one new and just add this new one without update other?

Answer (score 2):

```
>pod install --no-repo-update
```

This installs new pods without updating existing pods.

It's also just faster if you have a many of pods and want a fast install of a new pod.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the expected behavior of `pod install`. The only way I can see this happening is if you're not using the `Podfile.lock` as intended. When you specify something in your `Podfile` that you have never installed before, for example:

```
pod 'MyAwesomeLibrary', '~> 1.0.1'
```

The newest version matching your specification is determined (explained [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod)) and the resolved version is stored in the `Podfile.lock`. In this case that could mean that you actually download `1.0.4` etc.

This means when you go to add another library, for example:

```
pod 'AnotherAwesomeLibrary', '~> 2.0.1'
```

The same thing will happen for the new one. But, because of the information previously stored in your `Podfile.lock`, CocoaPods will just verify that the version specified there is installed. It **will not** update that library. If you actually want to update it you'll need to run `pod update`

Comment: I am asking it because previous developer modified pods .m and .h files and when I want to add new library and do pod install it wants to update other resources as well and modified files. Of course it replace previous sources with new ones.

Comment: Ah yes this is a terrible idea. You should for the library that was changed, apply your changes, and point CocoaPods to that instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
pod install --no-repo-update
```

thats it

Comment: This is exactly what [Kassem Itani](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44022119/369450) just said to do.